# Javafx exits fullscreen after showing dialog

Tags: javafx, dialog, fullscreen

When I show a dialog, full screen mode exits always. I have checked code in Windows, Linux and Mac OS. All gives same result. **How to prevent exiting fullscreen.** Please help me to resolve this.

**If this wont works I have to change platform javafx to some other technology to do my project :(**

```
public class JavaFxFullScreen extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            showAlert();
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public void showAlert() {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");

    alert.showAndWait();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}}
```

Comment: *"If this wont works I have to change platform javafx to some other technology to do my project :("* Or you simply display the `DialogPane` inside the fullscreen scene. I doubt that you'll find a technology that allows you to display other windows on top of a full-screen application since fullscreen mode is a optimized mode of the OS in case the only thing that needs to be displayed on screen is a single "window" that covers the whole screen.

Comment: @fabian But the problem is, I have already started development in javafx two weeks ago, and finished major functionality. :(

Answer (score 4):

You need set the owner of the Alert to the primary stage of your application.

```
public void showAlert(Stage owner) {
    Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Information Dialog");
    alert.setHeaderText("Look, an Information Dialog");
    alert.setContentText("I have a great message for you!");
    alert.initOwner(owner); // This sets the owner of this Dialog

    alert.showAndWait();
}
```

Then pass a reference to your primary Stage when you want to show your Alert.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            showAlert(primaryStage);
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing to try [`ControlsFX`](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) [`Notifications`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/Notifications.html)?

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import static javafx.application.Application.launch;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.Notifications;

public class JavaFXFullScreen extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event)
            {
                showAlert();
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public void showAlert()
    {
        Notifications.create()
                .title("Information Dialog")
                .text("I have a great message for you!")
                .showInformation();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```